# How do I check if a number string is in running sequence

Tags: c#, .net, regex, logic

Is there a regex (or any other way) to check if a numbers in a string is in running sequence?

E.g.,

```
"123456" will return true
"456789" will return true
"345678" will return true
"123467" will return false
"901234" will return false
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If all your sequences are composed of single-digit numbers, then you can solve this by observing that all correct sequences must be substrings of the longest such sequence, i.e. of `"0123456789"`. So the check can be done like this:

```
bool res = "0123456789".Contains(str);
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/0LykYS)

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
text.Skip(1).Zip(text, (c1, c0) => new { c1, c0 }).All(c => c.c1 - c.c0 == 1)
```